# How to update version in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, version

I have an app that has been put on the market, I want every time I change the version, the app will give an update reminder to the user.

Exam: I'm on version 2.0.0 + 99 but the market (CH Play,App store) is version 2.0.0 + 100, is there a way for the app to give an update for this case?

I have tried Upgrader Package and new_version package but it doesn't work because it checks local version is 2.0.0 and there is no change. I want to check +100 (2.0.0+100) what should I do?

Answer (score -1):

Write in terminal the following code:

```
flutter upgrade
```

And want to know more commands related to flutter write:

```
flutter --help
```

Comment: I want to update the version of the app on the market, not upgrade flutter